# Using MailKit to send email with multiple attachments

Tags: blazor, mailkit, iformfile

I am currently attempting to add a send mail feature to my Blazor application using MailKit.  I have been able to get it to send a text email and an html email.  My current problem is trying to send an email with multiple attachments.  I am using a Radzen Blazor component call Upload.  Upload stores the files in IFormFile and I need to extract them to add as attachments.

I have the following code and am unable to do anything other than add a single attachment.  Any help is appreciated!

Update:  I have added what I think is part of the solution...

I added List (IFormFile) file  and changed emailAttachment to file and it cleared the errors but will not compile and gives the error:

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS7036  There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'file' of 'AddEmailsComponent.SendEmail(List)'  PowerMoto   C:\powermoto\server\Pages\AddEmails.razor.designer.cs   453 Active

```
   private async Task SendEmail(List<IFormFile> file)
    {
        try
        {
            // create email message
            var email = new MimeMessage();
            email.From.Add(MailboxAddress.Parse(sender));
            email.To.Add(MailboxAddress.Parse(receiver));
            email.Subject = emailsubject;
            var multipart = new Multipart("mixed");
            multipart.Add(new TextPart(TextFormat.Html) { Text = emailMessage });
            foreach (var attachment in file)
            {
                var content = new MemoryStream();
                attachment.CopyTo(content);
                content.Position = 0;

                var contentType = ContentType.Parse(attachment.ContentType);
                var part = new MimePart(contentType.MimeType)
                {
                    FileName = Path.GetFileName(attachment.FileName),
                    ContentTransferEncoding = ContentEncoding.Base64,
                    Content = new MimeContent(content),
                };

                multipart.Add(part);
            }

            email.Body = multipart;
            //email.Body = new TextPart(TextFormat.Html) { Text = emailMessage};
            // send email
            using var smtp = new SmtpClient();
            smtp.Connect(outgoingServer, outgoingPort, SecureSocketOptions.Auto);
            smtp.Authenticate(userName, userPassword);
            smtp.Send(email);
            smtp.Disconnect(true);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            NotificationService.Notify(NotificationSeverity.Error, "Send Email Error!", ex.Message, 7000);
        }
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

```
var multipart = new Multipart ("mixed");
multipart.Add (new TextPart (TextFormat.Html) { Text = emailMessage });
foreach (var attachment in emailAttachments) {
    var content = new MemoryStream ();
    attachment.CopyTo (content);
    content.Position = 0;

    var contentType = ContentType.Parse (attachment.ContentType);
    var part = new MimePart (contentType.MimeType) {
        FileName = Path.GetFileName (attachment.FileName),
        ContentTransferEncoding = ContentEncoding.Base64,
        Content = new MimeContent (content),
    };

    multipart.Add (part);
}

email.Body = multipart;
```

Comment: Ok, I get the multipart and the foreach but how am I getting the IFormFile data into a MemoryStream.  I need to access the IFormFile and parse it to Attachments.  Your example is getting data from Memory Stream.  Sorry for my ignorance here.

Comment: BTW your send mail examples for mailkit were awesome to get me this far!  Thank You!

Comment: If IFormFile is not the right way to get the data for attachments, can someone point me in the right direction?  I want to be able to select multiple files and send them as attachments without limiting the number of attachments..

Comment: IFormFile has a CopyTo(Stream) method. My updated answer should be compilable now

Comment: I believe that is correct!  I am still having the issue with IFormFile.  It is clear that your telling me that the IFormFile content needs to be stored in the emailAttachments variable.  I still am unsure how to call IFormFile and store it in emailAttachments.  Again sorry for my ignorance here.

Comment: The `emailAttachments` variable is just what I assumed you called your list/array of IFormFiles.

Comment: This is where I get lost.  Whether it is emailAttachments or files or another variable name.  My problem is how and where do I access IFormFile.  Do I need to create a controller?  I can't seem to figure out how to get the attachments out.  I have a Radzen Control call "Upload" that will select the files for me and I just need to access and copy to stream.